# In an asp.net gridview how do I access a BoundField in the RowDataBound event?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How do I access the value of 'BoundField' in RowDataBound event of gridview?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem; 
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
{ 
if (drv["MYCOLNAME"] != DBNull.Value)
{
  var val = Convert.ToBoolean(drv["MYCOLNAME"]);
} 
}
```

Just convert to the correct type.

Answer (score 3):

The BoundField is specified **column wise** in a `GridView`, so basically `RowDataBound` is irrelevant here ;).

it can be accessed via

```
 GridView.Columns;
```

like

```
 BoundField b = myGridView.Columns[columnindex] as BoundField;
```

Comment: An alternative usage is when i want to access the BoundField of a field not bound to the GriView.