# How to get value from hidden column in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.

When I bounded gridview to sqldatasource ,I've selected all columns from the sql database.
And after this , I've removed my self some columns from the gridview.

Now , I want to get the value from the removed column without adding the column to the gridview.

THanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376278/how-to-hide-a-column-gridview-but-still-access-its-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the columns back to grid view and set their visible property to false, that way they won't render on the page but you would have access to them in code behind.

Comment: I did that but I'm not sure how to access the value

Comment: Check this (assuming your column is bounded field) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404914/in-an-asp-net-gridview-how-do-i-access-a-boundfield-in-the-rowdatabound-event